# Accessing WooCommerce bundle data during checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, product

I have a number of products in WC that have bundled equivalents where each bundle is just multiple quantities of the single product (e.g. pack of 6, 9, etc).

During checkout on a purchased bundle, I need to get the attributes of the parent product and the quantity multiplier for the bundle to multiply by the amount they added to the cart.

How do I do do this when I'm looping thru each item on the order?

```
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
    // ...
}
```

I checked and could not find the methods in `$item->get_product()` when called in the action `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed`.

[image]

Comment: You should have a look to WC Bundled products developer docs: [Data Structures and Storage](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/bundles/bundles-data-structures-storage/) You will be able to better understand how is structured the data, where to find it in database… and [Functions reference](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/bundles/bundles-functions-reference/) too.

Comment: Tried using these functions referenced, but all I get is `Call to undefined function wc_pb_get_bundled_order_item_container`